# Get consistency on scale from 0 to 100 from standard deviation js

Tags: javascript, math

As the title says I want to convert standard deviation to consistency on a scale from 0 to 100 but I'm unsure of how to accomplish this. So far I have a function to calculate the standard deviation but I don't know where to continue.

JS:

```
function standardDeviation(numArray) {
  const mean = numArray.reduce((s, n) => s + n) / numArray.length;
  const variance = numArray.reduce((s, n) => s + (n - mean) ** 2, 0) / (numArray.length - 1);
  return Math.sqrt(variance);
}
```

an example of the data would be like: `[1, 0.7193590816692575, 0.5724022479971302, 0.717924189884013, 0.8615329427239031, 0.7186416357766352, 0, 0.2863804854717206, 0.5745545856749971]`

output would be the consistency of these numbers perhaps something like 70%

if the input data was `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` the consistency would be 100%

Comment: do you have some data and wanted result?

Comment: Ill add some now